# WPF buttons not binding to view model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an WPF application with 8 buttons. Four of which work fine. I then added another 4 buttons. These button do not bind to my view model for some reason. When I click on the buttons nothing is called in my view model. Everything appears the same as the four working buttons to me and for the life of me I can't see why these new buttons do not bind to my view model?

**View Model**

```
 public ICommand CommandButtAppendComments { get; set; }   

 private bool _appendbuttVisibleComments;
 public bool AppendButtVisibleComents
    {
        get { return _appendbuttVisibleComments; }
        set
        {
            _appendbuttVisibleComments = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AppendButtVisibleComents");
        }
    }     

 public ViewModel()
    {            
        CommandButtAppendComments = new MyCommands(ExecuteCommandButtAppendComments, CanExecuteCommandButtAppendComments);

    }

   #region Append Comments Button
    private bool CanExecuteCommandButtAppendComments(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void ExecuteCommandButtAppendComments(object parameter)
    {
        AppendButtVisibleComents = false;
        DetachButtVisibleComents = true;
    }
    #endregion
```

**XAML**

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</Window.Resources>

  <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Height="30" Width="60" Content="Append" Command="{Binding CommandButtAppendComments}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" Visibility="{Binding AppendButtVisibleComents, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
```

Comment: In your question you said something about 8 Buttons, your example code only has one. Its difficult to understand the problem if the code you provide doesn't really show the problem. From what you showed i only see 2 minor issues. Not using INotifyPropertyChanged on the ICommand property and Naming it ButtonTemplate when you assign it to a Style.

Comment: try to remove the style

Comment: you're spelling is wrong... is it `CommandButtAppendComments` or `CommandButtAppendComents`

Comment: Yes my spelling was wrong however after correct the spelling the buttons were still not binding correctly. The issue was the grid that contained the buttons had its data context set to an incorrect object.